# All heading text has a line through in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just created this website
http://www.thebrainfreez10.com/

When I switch to the mobile/tablet view all heading tags get a line-through through  them.

Desktop View
[image]

Tablet View
[image]

Mobile view
[image]

I did not put any text-decoration to these tags.

I do not understand what is going wrong here.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with an emphasis on MINIMAL. Right now we need to dredge through all of your resources since you haven't provided any information as to when the problem began happening/which files are relevant.

Comment: Jonah first fix some of your code errors (over 70) https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thebrainfreez10.com%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `<s>` tag which renders as a strikethrough. It is probably a broken HTML tag in your markup.

Comment: Yeah my ctrl key is kinda not working properly so I mistakenly typed an 's' when I was saving.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below css for s tag for mobile view

```
text-decoration:none
```

It is applying the

```
text-decoration: line-through;
```

from user agent stylesheet